# Reading UTF-8 with BOM in ruby 2.5.0

Tags: ruby, csv, encoding, utf-8, utf

Is there a way to read files encoded in UTF-8 with BOM (Byte order marks) on Ruby v2.5.0?

On Ruby 2.3.1 this used to work:

```
 csv = CSV.open(file_path, encoding: 'bom|utf-8')
```

However, on 2.5.0 the following error ocurrs:

```
  ArgumentError:
    unknown encoding name - bom|utf-8
```

Comment: Can you try `BOM|utf-8` (BOM in capitals)

Comment: @knut - same result when using "BOM|utf-8", "BOM|utf8" , "BOM|UTF-8" or "BOM|UTF8"

Comment: [There's already a bug report.](https://github.com/ruby/csv/issues/23)

Comment: I ended up with: https://gist.github.com/romeuhcf/29132ebd3084b14901f8770f3baac3bf

Answer (score 2):

You can try this as well:

> File.open(file_path, "r:bom|utf-8")

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
require 'file_with_bom'

File.open(file_path, "w:utf-8", :bom => true ) do |csv|

end
```

it works well